Did CQ's WPX and WAZ awards die with the magazine?
As we know, CQ Magazine has breathed its last.
However, the CQ WPX and WAZ awards still show up in ARRL's LOTW.
Are those awards programs actually still alive?  (I mean they certainly could be -- since one has to pay for those awards it's always possible that the awards managers have decided to keep it going after the death of the magazine.)
Or have those awards programs died with the magazine?

WWROF continues the management of the CQ contests uninterrupted (as they have since 2015). I'm not sure if that extends to the WPX and WAZ awards, but emailing WWROF would probably result in a quick answer one way or the other.

Oh, good suggestion!  I'll try that and come back here if I get an answer.
